building a text editor with C++ and the cursor doesn't want to move
I'm a beginner so please don't go too harsh on me, I've been following a tutorial that a friend of mine gave for building a text editor with C++ on WSL, I've already built the functionalities for the arrow keys but they refuse to move for some reason.
I tried to change the editorMoveCursor function, adding additional if statements, that didn't work
I tried to change some thing with functions related to memory because i had a segmentation error before this so i though it could be related, didn't work.
/*** includes ***/


enum editorKey {
  ARROW_LEFT = 1000,
  ARROW_RIGHT,
  ARROW_UP,
  ARROW_DOWN,
  DEL_KEY,
  HOME_KEY,
  END_KEY,
  PAGE_UP,
  PAGE_DOWN
};
struct editorConfig {
  int cx, cy;
  int rowoff; // row offset
  int coloff; // column offset
  int screenrows;
  int screencols;
  int numrows;
  std::vector<erow> row;
  struct termios orig_termios;
};

editorConfig E;

/*** terminal ***/

void killswitch(const char *s) {
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b[2J", 4);
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b[H", 3);

  perror(s);
  exit(1);
}


int editorReadKey() {
  int nread;
  char c;
  while ((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1)) != 1) {
    if (nread == -1 && errno != EAGAIN) killswitch("read");
  }

  if (c == '\x1b') {
    char seq[3];

    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &seq[0], 1) != 1) return '\x1b';
    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &seq[1], 1) != 1) return '\x1b';

    if (seq[0] == '[') {
      if (seq[1] >= '0' && seq[1] <= '9') {
        if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &seq[2], 1) != 1) return '\x1b';
        if (seq[2] == '~') {
          switch (seq[1]) {
            case '1': return HOME_KEY;
            case '3': return DEL_KEY;
            case '4': return END_KEY;
            case '5': return PAGE_UP;
            case '6': return PAGE_DOWN;
            case '7': return HOME_KEY;
            case '8': return END_KEY;
          }
        }
      } else {
        switch (seq[1]) {
          case 'A': return ARROW_UP;
          case 'B': return ARROW_DOWN;
          case 'C': return ARROW_RIGHT;
          case 'D': return ARROW_LEFT;
          case 'H': return HOME_KEY;
          case 'F': return END_KEY;
        }
      }
    } else if (seq[0] == 'O') {
      switch (seq[1]) {
        case 'H': return HOME_KEY;
        case 'F': return END_KEY;
      }
    }

    return '\x1b';
  } else {
    return c;
  }
}

int getCursorPosition(int *rows, int *cols) {
  char buf[32];
  unsigned int i = 0;

  if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b[6n", 4) != 4) return -1;

  while (i < sizeof(buf) - 1) {
    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &buf[i], 1) != 1) break;
    if (buf[i] == 'R') break;
    i++;
  }
  buf[i] = '\0';

  if (buf[0] != '\x1b' || buf[1] != '[') return -1;
  if (sscanf(&buf[2], "%d;%d", rows, cols) != 2) return -1;

  return 0;
}





/*** output ***/
void editorScroll() { // to set the E.rowoff value
  if (E.cy < E.rowoff) { // check if cursor above window
    E.rowoff = E.cy;
  }
  if (E.cy >= E.rowoff + E.screenrows) { // check if moved outside window
    E.rowoff = E.cy - E.screenrows + 1;
  }
  if (E.cx < E.coloff) {
    E.coloff = E.cx;
  }
  if (E.cx >= E.coloff + E.screencols) {
    E.coloff = E.cx - E.screencols + 1;
  }
}

void editorDrawRows(abuf *ab) {
  int y;
  for (y = 0; y < E.screenrows; y++) {
    int filerow = y + E.rowoff; // to display each y position
    if (filerow >= E.numrows) {
      if (E.numrows == 0 && y == E.screenrows / 3) {
        char welcome[80];
        int welcomelen = snprintf(welcome, sizeof(welcome),
          "Kilo editor -- version %s", KILO_VERSION);
        if (welcomelen > E.screencols) welcomelen = E.screencols;
        int padding = (E.screencols - welcomelen) / 2;
        if (padding) {
          abAppend(ab, "~", 1);
          padding--;
        }
        while (padding--) abAppend(ab, " ", 1);
        abAppend(ab, welcome, welcomelen);
      } else {
        abAppend(ab, "~", 1);
      }
    } else {
      int len = E.row[filerow].rsize - E.coloff;
      if (len < 0) len = 0;
      if (len > E.screencols) len = E.screencols;
      abAppend(ab, &E.row[filerow].render[E.coloff], len);
    }

    abAppend(ab, "\x1b[K", 3);
    if (y < E.screenrows - 1) {
      abAppend(ab, "\r\n", 2);
    }
  }
}

void editorRefreshScreen() {
  editorScroll();
  abuf ab;

  abAppend(&ab, "\x1b[?25l", 6);
  abAppend(&ab, "\x1b[H", 3);

  editorDrawRows(&ab);

  char buf[32];
  snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "\x1b[%d;%dH", (E.cy - E.rowoff) + 1, (E.cx - E.coloff) + 1);
  abAppend(&ab, buf, strlen(buf));

  abAppend(&ab, "\x1b[?25h", 6);

  write(STDOUT_FILENO, ab.b, ab.len);
  abFree(&ab);
}

/*** input ***/

void editorMoveCursor(int key) {
  erow *row = (E.cy >= E.numrows) ? nullptr : &E.row[E.cy];
  switch (key) {
    case ARROW_LEFT:
      if (E.cx != 0) {
        E.cx--;
      } else if (E.cy > 0) {
        E.cy--;
        E.cx = E.row[E.cy].size;
      }
      break;
    case ARROW_RIGHT:
      if (row && E.cx < row->size) {
        E.cx++;
      } else if (row && E.cx == row->size) {
        E.cy++;
        E.cx = 0;
      }
      break;
    case ARROW_UP:
      if (E.cy != 0) {
        E.cy--;
      }
      break;
    case ARROW_DOWN:
      if (E.cy < E.numrows - 1) {
        E.cy++;
      }
      break;
  }
  row = (E.cy >= E.numrows) ? nullptr : &E.row[E.cy];
  int rowlen = row ? row->size : 0;
  if (E.cx > rowlen) {
    E.cx = rowlen;
  }
}

void editorProcessKeypress() {
  int c = editorReadKey();

  switch (c) {
    case CTRL_KEY('q'):
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b[2J", 4);
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b[H", 3);
      exit(0);
      break;

    case HOME_KEY:
      E.cx = 0;
      break;

    case END_KEY:
      E.cx = E.screencols - 1;
      break;

    case PAGE_UP:
    case PAGE_DOWN:
      {
        int times = E.screenrows;
        while (times--)
          editorMoveCursor(c == PAGE_UP ? ARROW_UP : ARROW_DOWN);
      }
      break;

    case ARROW_UP:
    case ARROW_DOWN:
    case ARROW_LEFT:
    case ARROW_RIGHT:
      editorMoveCursor(c);
      break;
  }
}



if you want the whole code its in here: https://github.com/AnasAlmukahal/text-editor-in-cpp/blob/main/kilo.cpp

Please show a [mre] within the question without relying on external links.

Did you try using a debugger?

@kiner_shah yes, it didnt provide anything

A debugger provides the ability to stop your program anywhere, step through execution and examine your program's state. That allows you to check what it's actually doing, and compare that to what you think it should be doing.

@MichaelKraiton When you say it didn't provide anything did you set a debug breakpoint on this line switch (seq[1]) { ? Did your code get there, and if so what was the content of seq[1]? And do you know how to single step and observe variables?

It works fine for me. Did you not open a file?

For what it is worth, I compiled kilo.cpp and ran it, and the arrow keys are working for me.  (Ctrl+q to quit.  Good safety tip!)  I suspect your terminals sequences for either the key input or the terminal manipulation (e.g., cursor positioning) output differ from what you are expecting.
